# Decimal to binary array

Tags: c

Basically, this program takes a decimal number from 1 to 10, that is the index of power of 2. And turns into an array with \$2^n\$ combinations.

For example: If my decimal is 1, I'll have 2 arrays, `[0]` and `[1]`, and if my decimal is 2, I'll have 4 combinations, `[0 0]`; `[0 1]`; `[1 0]`; `[1 1]`, and so on. I cannot use `break` conditions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, q = 1, i, f, d, p, vet[10]; // n: index; q: combinations; i, f, d, p: ints for operations; 

    scanf ("%d", &n); //index

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){ // getting total number of comb
        q *= 2;
    }
     n--;

    for (i = 0; i < q; i++){
        f = i;

        for (p = 0; p < 10; p++){   //setting array to 0
            vet[p] = 0;
        }

        while ( f > 0){ 
           p = 1;
           d = 0;

            while (f >= 2*p){
                p *= 2;
                d++;
            }

            vet[d] = 1; //changing position 'd' on array for 1. 
            f -= p;
        }

        // printing results
        printf ("f: %d bin:", i);

        for (p = 0; p < 10; p++)
            printf ("%d", vet[9-p]);

        printf ("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use clear variable names that explain what they are used for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some comments:

- There is no need to store the results in memory, so don't. Simply output them as they are computed.
- It's been many years since C has allowed variables to be declared where they're used instead of being lumped together at the top. Do this for legibility.
- Don't loop through to get q. Powers of 2 are easily found via << .
- Don't loop through to reset the array contents to 0. Simply set the elements to their desired value.
- Don't populate an array forward and then loop back through it in reverse to do an output. Simply populate a string that is ready to be output.
- `f` doesn't mean anything to the program user, so don't use it in the output; use something like "decimal" instead.

An alternative implementation is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    char *output = malloc(n+1);
    output[n] = '\0';

    for (int number = 0; number < (1 << n); number++)
    {
        int temp_num = number;
        for (int idx = n-1; idx >= 0; idx--)
        {
            output[idx] = '0' + (temp_num & 1);
            temp_num >>= 1;
        }
        printf("dec: %d bin: %s\n", number, output);
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Code is faulty.  `printf("dec: %d bin: %s\n", number, output);` attempting to print an array that may lack a null character -  UB.  `output[n-1] = '\0';` serves no purpose.  Consider `n==1`.

Comment: @chux Good catch - will update. However, the null absolutely does serve a purpose - it was simply misplaced. malloc does not initialize content.

Comment: I just realize I must not to use bitwise operators, and use only stdio.h library, Since I don't understand a lot about those topics. Is it possible?

Comment: @IgorBraga If you don't understand it, now's the time to learn :)

Comment: My knowlegde is limited so far by functions and pointers. I am about to learn archives first, then structure, and by the end, bit operations. I don't want to advance a lot now, baby steps you know.

Answer (score 2):

As there seems to be no explicit question in the OP I will simply point out some things that could be improved.

- Use variable names that describe what the variable is being used for

Generally you want to avoid variable names consisting only of one character. If you pick meaningful names then you also won't need comments explaining what they do.

- Don't reinvent the wheel

Some of your code can be rewritten using standard library functions (unless you are not allowed to use those either)

Examples of this are:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){ // getting total number of comb
        q *= 2;
    }
```

You can use `pow` here

(as people pointed out in the comments only use `pow` when not dealing with integers)

```
q = pow(2, n);
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow

And

```
for (p = 0; p < 10; p++){   //setting array to 0
            vet[p] = 0;
        }
```

You can use memset instead

```
    memset(vet, 0, sizeof(int) * 10);
```

See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset

- Be consistent

You always use the brackets for your statements but then later omit them for no good reason

```
for (p = 0; p < 10; p++)
            printf ("%d", vet[9-p]);
```

- Keep it simple

If you don't need to format your ouput you can simply use

`puts("");`

instead of `printf`

These are just some things I noticed. I'm sure other people with better knowledge of C can give you additional advice.

Comment: Don't use `pow` for integer powers of 2; use `<<` instead.

Comment: Avoid `pow` for integers, always.

Comment: OP's for loop is OK.  `memset(vet, 0, sizeof(int) * 10);` is better as `memset(vet, 0, sizeof vet);`

Comment: Note: `printf ("\n");` may emit the same code as `puts("");`  Code for clarity.

Comment: "only use pow when not dealing with integers", then why is "you can use `pow` here" suggested in this answer?